# Not unique table/alias when querying database

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I'm running the query

```
SELECT `transactions`.`transaction_id`,`transactions`.`from_user_id`,`transactions`.`to_user_id`,`transactions`.`amount`,`transactions`.`description`,`users`.`first_name`,`users`.`last_name`,`transactions`.*,`users`.`first_name`,`users`.`last_name`,`transactions`.*,`users`.`user_id`,`users`.`first_name`,`users`.`last_name`,`transactions`.*,`users`.`user_id`,`users`.`first_name`,`users`.`last_name` FROM transactions
LEFT JOIN `login`.`users` ON `transactions`.`to_user_id` = `users`.`user_id` 
LEFT JOIN `login`.`users` ON `transactions`.`from_user_id` = `users`.`user_id`
```

on this this database [image: Database Schema]

When I try to run the query, I get the error `#1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'users'`. I'm trying to get a list of transactions with the names of both users who are part of the transaction.

Comment: Why are you selecting all the columns over and over?

Comment: @Strawberry I used the graphical builder in phpmyadmin - I'm not great with SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like:

```
SELECT t.*
     , u1.user_id    to_user_id
     , u1.first_name to_first_name
     , u1.last_name  to_last_name
     , u2.user_id    from_user_id
     , u2.first_name from_first_name
     , u2.last_name  from_last_name
  FROM transactions t
  LEFT 
  JOIN users u1
    ON u1.user_id = t.to_user_id
  LEFT 
  JOIN users u2
    ON u2.user_id = t.from_user_id
```

Note that it's amazingly unlikely that a column called `amount` or `balance` would be FLOAT. See DECIMAL.

Comment: Issue was because Alias of the table users were not defined so they were not unique and thats' why it cannot be resolved.